# Gulp-plumber not found in Ubuntu OS, but found in Windows OS on dual boot

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am following a tutorial, and I am supposed to have a gulpfile.js running, but I'm encountering a strange situation. Gulp works in one location and does not work in the other.
I have a dual boot for Ubuntu and Windows 8.1. In the Ubuntu OS Documents directory the gulp command does not work, but returns an error saying "'gulp-plumber' not found". I don't understand why since the folder structure is exactly the same. If I change directory to the windows volume and access the main project folder, when I type "gulp" everything works fine.

Additionally, if I CTRL-C in the command line, the gulp command stops working and returns an error saying:

> events.js:163
>
> ```
>  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ```
>
> Error: write EPIPE

So how can I run the gulp command again? Is it through ps aux, check something running and then kill it?

github.com/DannyS95/Project

Comment: Show us come code, please.

Comment: gulp plumber is meant for those 'Unhandled error' event . Have you tried npm installing it ?

Comment: Hello guys, i have npm, gulp and node installed with the latest versions, i also have the node_modules folder, is there a way to show you my project by uploading it somewhere? edit: i am currently trying to upload my project to github.

Comment: https://github.com/DannyS95/Project finally i got it uploaded to github, check the project guys and see if something is missing please, i am realy desperate here.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed, i had to install gulp plumber, because i did not have that package in the package.json file.
Then a quick npm install, and since i have gulp globally i can just run gulp and voila, it works.